# The column space of a matrix A is the set of solutions of Ax = b?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it true to state , The column space of a matrix A is the set of solutions of Ax = b?
Why?

Comment: No, I'd say that $b$ is *in* the column space of $A$. So the column space is the *image* of the linear function represented by $A$.

Comment: The column space is the set of all $Ax$ for all $x$.

Comment: The column space is the set of all vectors b such that $Ax=b$ has a solution for x.

Answer (score 1):

The column space of a matrix $A$ is defined as the span of the columns of $A$, hence the name.

It turns out that this is also the set $\{b:\text{ there exists } x \text{ such that } Ax=b\}$.

Answer (score 1):

[Kuldeep Singh's *Linear Algebra: Step by Step*](https://maths-for-all.co.uk/linear-algebra/)
(2013) p 253 answers this on pp. 263-264,  but typo is "Exercises 3.6" that ought "Exercise 3.13".

[image]

and as Exercise 3.6.13 on p 268.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct. To see this consider $Ax=b$ of the form:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)x=\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right)$$

Then the column space of $A$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, however it is clear that a vector such as $\left(\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 1\end{array}\right)$ is not a solution to above.